# SQL Syntax Error near ADD

Tags: sql, mysql

I've been staring at this thing for a while now and I can't seem to figure out what the syntax error is. I've been in this situation before and last time it was something so unbelievably simple I felt stupid afterwards. But here's to another attempt:

```
//update database
$q = "
 UPDATE 
  users 
 SET 
  id='$edit_id',
  name='$edit_name',
  bdm='$edit_bdm',
  add='$edit_add',
  pc='$edit_pc',
  location='$edit_outletL',
  style='$edit_outletS',
  coName='$edit_coName',
  coNum='$edit_coTel',
  coEmail='$edit_coEmail',
  password='$edit_pass'
 WHERE
  id='$query_title'
";
$edit_query = mysql_query($q) or die("Database Query Error: ". mysql_error());
```

Database Query Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add='Llancadle, Nr Barry', pc='CF62 3AQ', location='rural', style='food', coName' at line 1
```

Comment: escape field names by surrounding them with back-tick like ``add``

Comment: Why is there a vote to close? It's a perfectly acceptable question to ask is it not?

Comment: Have you tried other values for the variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You neeed to backquote add since it is a keyword:

```
`add` = ...
```

Comment: I suppose that's the danger of only scratching the surface of MySQL's capabilities, I can't recognise errors like this. Cheers mate!

Comment: The general advice is to backquote all the field names and table names to avoid such errors.

Comment: lol - that's just a ridiculous suggestion.

Comment: If you create a SELECT query in phpMyAdmin, it backquotes everything for you so I can see where @Nylon's suggestion came from

Answer (score 3):

I think [`add`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/reserved-words.html) is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is that "add" is a MySQL reserved word. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html. If you have a column named "add", escape it like this:

```
//update database
    $edit_query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET id='$edit_id', name='$edit_name', bdm='$edit_bdm', `add`='$edit_add', pc='$edit_pc', location='$edit_outletL', style='$edit_outletS', coName='$edit_coName', coNum='$edit_coTel', coEmail='$edit_coEmail', password='$edit_pass' WHERE id='$query_title'") or die("Database Query Error: ". mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

as bobby noted in a comment, add is a mysql reserved word

```
`add`='$edit_add'
```

will tell mysql you are talking about a column