# mysql Erorr when use select ?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

i have a problem , each time i try to do select and fetch this error show

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add' at line 1**

```
  <?php
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123") or die() ; 
 mysql_select_db("boom") or die() ; 
 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $select= "select * from add" ;
 $data = mysql_query($select) or die(); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 echo "<img src=images/".$info['photo'] .">";
 }
 //Outputs the image and other data
 ?>
```

what is the problem here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656487/sql-syntax-error-near-add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that 'add' is the table name (add is a reserved word), and try escaping your table name with the ` character.

Backticks are good practise to escape the table name for MySQL (Next to the 1 on your keyboard).

```
SELECT * FROM `add`
```

Comment: it worked ! , thanks :) where i can found this character on the keyboard ?

Answer (score 4):

`add` is a reserved word:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Rewrite the query like so:

```
$select= "select * from `add`" ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$select = "select * from `add` ;
```

Adding the backticks will solve your problem. ADD is a reserved word in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

"Add" is a reserved word in MySQL.  You can either change the name of your table, or escape it out.  According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) it looks like you would need to put backticks around the table name, like `add`.

Comment: Backticks ` **not** single quotes